# How do I delete a row from a Parse object?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a class on Parse.com called "Hospital", which has a few rows on it. I want to query all the rows in this object, and then selectively delete some of them.

I figure I need to cycle through the object, gathering the objectIDs, and then look at the row associated with each ID to figure out which ones should be deleted. I can't find how to do this anywhere. I've tried this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hospital"];
```

But this returns an object with 0 objects inside it, when there is definitely a row in the Parse.com database.

Once I get this part working, and get objectIDs, it seems I can delete a row with the following:

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Hospital" objectId:@"NMZ8gLj3RE"];
 [testObject deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
 if (succeeded){
 NSLog(@"BOOOOOM"); // this is my function to refresh the data
 } else {
 NSLog(@"DELETE ERRIR");
 }
 }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hospital"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *hospitals, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        for (PFObject *hospital in hospitals)
        {
            if ([hospital.objectId isEqualToString:@"NMZ8gLj3RE"])
            {
                [hospital deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (succeeded){
                        NSLog(@"BOOOOOM"); // this is my function to refresh the data
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"DELETE ERRIR");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }

}];
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it's still saying that the Hospital object has no objects inside it, and so the hospitals array is empty.

Comment: Please check the correct spelling of the classes (case sensitive). If the spelling is off it will return an empty array. Maybe you could include a screenshot of your parse dashboard with the Hospital classes open.

Comment: WAIT I got it! I think there is a race condition haha. Thanks a lot! Heres a check, I'd upvote you but I don't have the rep yet.